# How to measure the time taken by storm job

Tags: apache-storm

I want to benchmark my topology with different parallelism_hint. In order to test it, i prepare a 1G log file to emit to Storm. The problem is how can i measure the time taken by my topology programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

time like latency or what? You can see latencies for every component on Storm UI.

[image]

Also, there is a "capacity" column -- if you have bottlenecks that you need to scale, their capacity will be close or higher that 1.

This statistics is also can be fetched programatically via Storm REST api.

Comment: The Storm UI is really simple but useful. So does it mean that if the capacity is much lower than 1, then it is not necessary to increment the parallelism_hint.

Comment: @yunfeng.guo well, AFAIK capacity is about being *CPU bound* -- so if you're parsing something, or perform heavy calculations, yes, capacity much lower than 1 can be ignored, not sure about IO bound operations

Comment: No, there is no heavy calculations. The only job my bolt does is read data from mongodb and then update it. So I guess even i increment the parallelism_hint for my 'UPDATE_MONGODB_BOLT', it may not get better performance, because the bottleneck is the DB connection, am I right?

Comment: The problem was resolved after i created index in mongo :) Anyway, Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many tuples your spout is going to emit and if you have fault-tolerance enabled, you can simple count all incoming acks... Basically, take a startup timestamp in `Spout.open(...)`, count the call to `Spout.ack()` and if the count reaches the input size, take a final timestamp.